# Show a set is dense in $C(X)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a totally discontinuous compact space. Show that the algebra generated by $$\{f_F; ~f_F=\chi_F-\chi_{X/F},F \text{ is a clopen subset of }X\}$$ is dense in $C(X)$.

My attempt: Suppose $\{x_i\}$ is a countable dense subset in X and for every $i\geq 1$,  $F_i$ is a clopen subset containing $x_i$. For every $f\in C(X)$, $\epsilon >0, $ and for every $i\in \Bbb N$, there is $\alpha_i\in\Bbb Q$ such that $|f(x_i)-\alpha_i|< \epsilon/2$.

To show $||f- \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i f_{F_i}||<\epsilon$, I have two problems.

I have $|f(x)-\sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i f_{F_i}(x)|\leq|f(x)-f(x_i)|+|f(x_i) - \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i f_{F_i}(x)|$. my problem is that maybe $x$ belongs to $F_i$ and $F_j$ where $i\not=j$. In this case I can not use $|f(x_i)-\alpha_i|< \epsilon/2$.

My another problem is showing $||f- \sum_{i=1}^n \alpha_i f_{F_i}||<\epsilon$.

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: totally disconnected?

Comment: Do you use the continuity of $f$? $x_i$ is chosen to be very close to $x$.

Comment: yes, means if $x\in X $ , U is an open neighborhood of x,then there is a clopen subset $V$ of $X$ such that $x\in V\subset U$

Comment: Shine@ I use continuty of f to show that $|f(x) - f(x_i)|< \epsilon/2$. I do not have any difficulty in this part.

Comment: Is it probably "totally disconnected"?

Comment: Sorry, I correct it.

Comment: Where do you use the totally disconnectedness of X?

Comment: To show clopen subsets are a basis for X and after that I do not use

Comment: Take a look at the Stone-Weierstraß theorem.

Comment: But I want to proof it without using Stone-Weierstrass theorem.